# How can I know get a star on a place i click?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to draw the stars when I click the screen. Like I kinda get how I need to do it, but the once i've tried haven't worked and it gives an error:

> AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'onScreenClick'

And sometimes it says I need to add 'fun' into it?

```
#2.7 Tähtikirkas yö paranneltu versio.

#Tähtikirkas yö
import turtle as t
from random import randint, random

def draw_star(points, size, col, x, y):
    t.speed(80)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown
    angle = 180 - (180 / points)
    t.color(col)
    t.begin_fill()
    for i in range(points):
        t.forward(size)
        t.right(angle)
    t.end_fill()

#pääohjelma
t.Screen().bgcolor('light yellow')

while True:
    ranPts = randint(5, 5) * 2 + 1
    ranSize = randint(20, 50)
    ranCol = (random(), random (), random())
    ranX = randint(-350, 300)
    ranY = randint(-250, 250)
    draw_star(ranPts, ranSize, ranCol, ranX, ranY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of screen is `onclick()`, or the global function `onscreenclick()`.  The argument to the method/function is the name of one of your functions to call when the user clicks on the window.  Your function is expected to take `x` and `y` arguments.  Below is a rework of your code to allow the user to light up the sky by clicking rather than doing it randomly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, random

def draw_star(points, size, color, x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    angle = 180 - (180 / points)

    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(points):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)

    turtle.end_fill()

def click_sky(x, y):
    ranPts = randint(2, 5) * 2 + 1
    ranSize = randint(20, 50)
    ranColor = (random(), random(), random())

    draw_star(ranPts, ranSize, ranColor, x, y)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('light yellow')
screen.onclick(click_sky)
screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Ay, appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Even tho after like 20stars that starts drawing weird looking lines:D but that's fine